# ValidatesOnDataErrors=True how to highlight multiple fields?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, validation, mvvm

I have a input form in WPF that takes three numerical values: A lower value, a middle value and an upper value. I've set ValidatesOnDataErrors to true for the binding of the lower and the middle value and in the corresponding object I check if the lower value is actually lower than the middle/upper value as well as I check if the middle value is actually lower than the upper value.
This works when the user modifies the lower and the middle value. However if the user modifies the upper value then the validation of couse is not triggered. Same for the middle value: If the middle value is changed then the check if the lower val is lower than middle one is not triggered.

Of course I could check all values in all validation cases, but is this really neccessary? Can I somehow trigger the validation of the binding of the lower and middle value whenever the upper value is modified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your Model implements [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). So in the setter of each property you could trigger the notification for another 2 properties. It should be something like:

```
public string Top
{
    get { return _top; }
    set
    {
        _top = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(x=>x.Middle);
        OnPropertyChanged(x=>x.Bottom);
    }
}
```

The notification that is sent to other properties will trigger their validation again.